# Login and registration using Nodejs + express, user data undefined

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I have a simple registration page which should store the users input (name,email,password) in a database. I am using express and node. The thing i wanted to try is to have all the database operations (insert,select etc) for registration in one file and send the response to the server from another file.

dbQuery.js

```
var express=require("express");
var app = express();
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'user_name',
  password : 'password',
  database : 'database'
});
connection.connect(function(err){
if(!err) {
    console.log("Database is connected");
} else {
    console.log("Error while connecting with database");
}
});

 module.exports.register=function(callback){
 app.get('/register',function(req,res){
  var today = new Date();
    var users={
        "name":req.body.name,
        "email":req.body.email,
        "password":req.body.password,
        "created_at":today,
        "updated_at":today
    }
      return connection.query('INSERT INTO users SET ?',users, callback) 
}
}
```

app.js

```
var express=require("express");
var connection = require('./dbQuery');
var app = express();
app.post('/register',function(req,res){
  connection.register(function(error, results, fields){
   if (error) {
        res.json({
            status:false,
            message:'there are some error with query for registration'
        })
      }else{
        console.log('is it coming here in else')
          res.json({
            status:true,
            data:results,
            message:'user registered sucessfully'
        })
      }
    })
})
```

index.html

```
<html>  
    <body>  
        <form action="/register" method="POST">  
            First Name: <input type="text" name="name">  

            Email: <input type="text" name="email">
            Password: <input type="password" name="password">

            <input type="submit" value="Submit">  
        </form>
    </body>  
</html>
```

When i execute app.js the server just keep loading without giving anything

I expected the output should be displaying the json response on server i.e 'user successfully registered' ,but it keeps on loading.

Comment: Why isn't your POST api block - function not returning anything?

Comment: when i execute the app.js and go to the localhost, it doesnt return any response to the server, instead it keeps on loading.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing dbQuery.js to this:

```
var mysql = require("mysql");
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "user_name",
  password: "password",
  database: "database"
});
connection.connect(function(err) {
  if (!err) {
    console.log("Database is connected");
  } else {
    console.log("Error while connecting with database");
  }
});

module.exports.register = function(callback) {
  var today = new Date();
  var users = {
    name: req.body.name,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password,
    created_at: today,
    updated_at: today
  };
  connection.query("INSERT INTO users SET ?", users, callback);
};
```

Comment: I did try this, it give me an error on the server stating that the 'name is not equal to undefined'. I also tried to put a console.log(users); after the users variable to see if the values are getting assigned or not, but nothing is getting printed on the console

Comment: Good, the register function is executing now. The new error means that you are not passing the req params to the 'register' function. Try to pass 'name', 'email' and 'password' along with the callback function.

Comment: So in place of function(callback) i have to pass function(name,email,password,callback)  and change the user variable value like name from { name: req.body.name}, to {name:name}

Comment: Yes, that is one way. Also please take a look at https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser to extract POST parameters.

Comment: I made the above changes to the code it gave me the following error.      throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
Error: ER_BAD_NULL_ERROR: Column 'email' cannot be null. The user variable values getting printed is, { name: [Function],
  email: undefined,
  password: undefined,
  }

Answer (score 0):

You are doing wrong, here if am posting simple steps for an API by express

### Your app.js file should be

```
  var createError = require('http-errors');
    var express = require('express');
    var path = require('path');
    var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
    var logger = require('morgan');
    const i18n = require("i18n");
    var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
// this is the api file created under the routes folder 
    var apiRouter = require('./routes/api');
    require('./database')

    var app = express();

    app.use(i18n.init);

    i18n.configure({
      locales: ['en', 'de'],
      cookie: 'LocalLang',
      defaultLocale: 'en',
      extension: ".json",
      directory: __dirname + '/locales',
      register: global,
      logDebugFn: function (msg) {
        console.log('debug', msg);
      },
      logWarnFn: function (msg) {
        console.log('warn', msg);
      },
      logErrorFn: function (msg) {
        console.log('error', msg);
      }
    });
    // view engine setup
    app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

    app.use(logger('dev'));
    app.use(express.json());
    app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
    app.use(cookieParser());
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

    app.use('/', indexRouter);
    app.use('/api', apiRouter);

    // catch 404 and forward to error handler
    app.use(function (req, res, next) {
      next(createError(404));
    });

    // error handler
    app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
      // set locals, only providing error in development
      res.locals.message = err.message;
      res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

      // render the error page
      res.status(err.status || 500);
      res.render('pages/error');
    });

    module.exports = app;
```

### In you api.js file which is required in app.js file

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
//Import your query.js file 
const query = require('path for the file ./query')

router.post('/register',query.register)

module.exports = router;
```

### query.js file should be like

```
 var mysql      = require('mysql');
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
      host     : 'localhost',
      user     : 'user_name',
      password : 'password',
      database : 'database'
    });
    connection.connect(function(err){
    if(!err) {
        console.log("Database is connected");
    } else {
        console.log("Error while connecting with database");
    }
    });
    exports.register = (req, res)=>{
    var today = new Date();
      var users = {
        name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password,
        created_at: today,
        updated_at: today
      };
      connection.query("INSERT INTO users SET ?", users, (error,result)=>{
    if(err)
     return res.send({status:false, message:"Error in savind data in db"})

    return res.send({status:true, message:"Resgistered sucessfully"})
  });
 }
```

Comment: I figured out, changes required were in (dbQuery.js)  **`module.exports.register = function(callback)`** changed to  **`module.exports.register = function(req,res,callback)`** and in (app.js) **`connection.register(function(error, results, fields)`** to **`connection.authenticate(req,res,function (error, results, fields)`**